# How to use Reflection with Non-Generic Types

Tags: c#, linq, system.reflection

I've spent hours on here looking for an answer to my problem so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate query. If so, please point me in the right direction. If not, see below, I've been tasked with the following:

Create a function that can, **dynamically**, check the database to see if a value is present for a certain object.

Basically, the user clicks a button which moves an item to another Stage. The next stage **may/may not** have requirements before being able to enter that stage. If requirements are present, there are two data points sent to me:

- **ReflectionClass** (string) [*I will either use the DbSet string value OR the Class string value here*]
- **ReflectionProperty** (string)

With these two pieces of data I need to check the database (*via DbSet preferably, using LINQ or Reflection*).

The **ReflectionClass** variable can refer to one of 5 tables in the database. So, essentially, I need a way to say: `db.[DbSet].Any(w=>w.ID == PipelineID && w.[ReflectionProperty] != null)` or something like this...

I've tried using ExpressionTrees but I can't get the `Func<T,bool>` to work with a `Type` variable. See my code below, this will work, but I know there is a more efficient way to do this using Reflection, I just don't know how.

```
public async Task<Feedback> vStageReqFields(Guid NextStageID, Guid PipelineID)
{
  Feedback f = new Feedback();
  bool Valid = true;
  string InvalidList = string.Empty;
  List<Domain.Pipeline.Pipeline> pipelines = new List<Domain.Pipeline.Pipeline>();
  List<Domain.Pipeline.Billing> billings = new List<Domain.Pipeline.Billing>();
  try
  {
    //Get a list of Validations needed before advancing Stage...
    var validations = db.PipelineStageRequiredFields.Any(a=>a.StageID == NextStageID) ? db.PipelineStageRequiredFields.Where(w=>w.StageID == NextStageID).ToList() : null;
    //If Validations exist, start validatiing...
    if(validations != null && validations.Any())
    {
      Type objectType = (from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                         from type in asm.GetTypes()
                         where type.IsClass && type.FullName == "Domain.Pipeline.Pipeline" // static class to find Assembly info, all v.ReflectionClasses come from the same Assembly...
                         select type).SingleOrDefault();          
      foreach (var v in validations)
      {
        if(Utility.HasProperty(objectType, v.RefelectionProperty))//Check to see if ReflectionsClass has ReflectionProperty
        {
          //Switch Statement for Reflection Class to Check Property Value...
          switch (v.RefelectionClass)
          {
            case "Domain.Pipeline.Pipeline":
            pipelines = GetAllMembers(db, "Pipelines").OfType<Domain.Pipeline.Pipeline>().Where(w => w.ID == PipelineID).ToList(); //Get all Pipeline Objects...
            if (pipelines.Any())
            {
              var model = pipelines.FirstOrDefault();
              var value = model.GetType().GetProperty(v.RefelectionProperty).GetValue(model, null); //Check if Required ReflectionProperty has a value...
              if (value == null)
              {
                Valid = false;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(InvalidList))
                {
                  InvalidList = "The following fields are required: " + v.RefelectionProperty;
                }
                else
                {
                  InvalidList = InvalidList + ", " + v.RefelectionProperty;
                }
              }
            }
            else
            {
              f.Success = false;
              f.Type = FeedbackType.Error;
              f.SuccessMsg = "Error: Could not find a Pipeline with this ID: '" + PipelineID.ToString() + "'";
            }
            break;
          case "Domain.Pipeline.Billing":
            billings = GetAllMembers(db, "Billings").OfType<Domain.Pipeline.Billing>().Where(w => w.PipelineID == PipelineID).OrderByDescending(o => o.EffectiveDate).ToList();
            if (billings.Any())
            {
              var model = billings.FirstOrDefault();
              var value = model.GetType().GetProperty(v.RefelectionProperty).GetValue(model, null);
              if (value == null)
              {
                Valid = false;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(InvalidList))
                {
                  InvalidList = "The following fields are required: " + v.RefelectionProperty;
                }
                else
                {
                  InvalidList = InvalidList + ", " + v.RefelectionProperty;
                }
              }
            }
            else
            {
              f.Success = false;
              f.Type = FeedbackType.Error;
              f.SuccessMsg = "Error: Could not find a Pipeline with this ID: '" + PipelineID.ToString() + "'";
            }
            break;
          default:
            f.Success = false;
            f.Type = FeedbackType.Error;
            f.SuccessMsg = "Error: Could not find any Data in the " + v.RefelectionClass + " table for this Pipeline: '" + PipelineID.ToString() + "'";
            break;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          f.Success = false;
          f.Type = FeedbackType.Error;
          f.SuccessMsg = "The " + v.RefelectionClass + " does not have a Property of " + v.RefelectionProperty;             
        }
      }
    }
    //No Validations Exist, User can proceed...
    else
    {
      f.Success = true;
      f.Type = FeedbackType.Success;
      f.SuccessMsg = "Success! There are no required fields for the next stage.";
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    f.Success = false;
    f.Type = FeedbackType.Error;
    f.SuccessMsg = ITool.GetExceptionDetails(ex);
  }
  return f;
}
```

Here is the other function:

```
static IEnumerable GetAllMembers(DbContext DB, string dbSetName)
{
  var model = DB.GetType().GetProperty(dbSetName);
  return (IEnumerable)model.GetValue(DB);
}
```

Comment: `The ReflectionClass variable can refer to one of 5 tables in the database` but the switch only caters for two?

Comment: @Nkosi, yes, that's correct. I put these two case statements in, then realized there must be an easier way to accomplish this task, therefore, they're only temporary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following refactoring to remove repeated code and allow it to be more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

```
public Feedback vStageReqFields(Guid NextStageID, Guid PipelineID) {
    Feedback feedback = new Feedback();
    List<string> required = new List<string>();
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        //Get a list of Validations needed before advancing Stage...
        var validations = db.PipelineStageRequiredFields.Where(w => w.StageID == NextStageID);
        //If Validations exist, start validatiing...
        if (validations.Any()) {
            foreach (var field in validations) {
                var className = field.RefelectionClass;
                object model = null;
                //Switch Statement for Reflection Class to Check Property Value...
                switch (className) {
                    case "Domain.Pipeline.Pipeline":
                        model = db.Pipelines.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == PipelineID);
                        break;
                    case "Domain.Pipeline.Billing":
                        model = db.Billings.Where(w => w.PipelineID == PipelineID).OrderByDescending(o => o.EffectiveDate).FirstOrDefault();
                        break;
                    default:
                        errors.Add("Could not find any Data in the " + className + " table for this Pipeline: '" + PipelineID.ToString() + "'");
                        continue;
                }
                validate(field, PipelineID, model, required, errors);
            }

            if (required.Any()) {
                msg.Append("The following fields are required: ")
                    .AppendLine(string.Join(", ", required));
            }
            if (errors.Any()) {
                msg.AppendLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors));
            }
        }
        if (msg.Length > 0) {
            feedback.Success = false;
            feedback.Type = FeedbackType.Error;
            feedback.SuccessMsg = msg.ToString();
        } else {
            feedback.Success = true;
            feedback.Type = FeedbackType.Success;
            feedback.SuccessMsg = "Success! There are no required fields for the next stage.";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        feedback.Success = false;
        feedback.Type = FeedbackType.Error;
        feedback.SuccessMsg = ITool.GetExceptionDetails(ex);
    }
    return feedback;
}
```

Use strong typing to find the desired object model.

The supporting `validate` method looks like this

```
private void validate(PipelineStageRequiredField field, Guid PipelineID, object model, List<string> required, List<string> errors) {
    if (model != null) {
        var propertyName = field.RefelectionProperty;
        var objectType = model.GetType();
        var propertyInfo = getProperty(objectType, propertyName);
        if (propertyInfo != null) {
            var isValidModel = buildRequiredFieldCheckDelegate(objectType, propertyInfo);
            if (!(bool)isValidModel.DynamicInvoke(model)) {
                required.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
            }
        } else {
            errors.Add("The " + field.RefelectionClass + " does not have a Property of " + propertyName);
        }
    } else {
        errors.Add("Error: Could not find a " + field.RefelectionClass + " with this Pipeline: '" + PipelineID.ToString() + "'");
    }
}

private static PropertyInfo getProperty(Type type, string propertyName) {
    return type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Where an expression can be built to check that the required field has a value

```
private Delegate buildRequiredFieldCheckDelegate(Type type, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
    //Func<T, bool>
    var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type, typeof(bool));
    var prpertyDefaultValue = getDefaultValue(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
    // p => p.Property != default(typeof(TProperty))

    // p =>
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    // p => p.Property
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
    // default(TProperty);
    var defaultValue = Expression.Constant(prpertyDefaultValue);
    // p => p.Property != default(TProperty)
    var body = Expression.NotEqual(property, defaultValue);
    // Func<T, bool> = T p => p.Property != default(TProperty)
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, body, parameter);

    return lambda.Compile();
}

private static object getDefaultValue(Type type) {
    return type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, but I was hoping to **replace** the `Switch/Case` with a **Dynamic** method of accomplishing the same result. Sorry, I don't believe I was that specific in my above needs. So, instead of using `Switch/Case`, I could pass either the `DbSet` or `Class` with the `PropertyName` and then check for a value without needing a `Switch/Case`. Is this doable?

Comment: @ColeLeffel I left the switch in based on what was provided in original question. But there should be some indicator of how you intend to differentiate the retrieval of the different types

Comment: @ColeLeffel Especially since there were different ways to get the required item.

Comment: You're right. The `switch` would need to remain, but there would only need to be 2 cases. The main `Type` (Pipeline) and all other `Types` (Billing, Schedule, Supervision, JobSetup, etc). **Case 1: "Pipeline"** This `Type` uses **only** the **PipelineID** parameter with a `DbContext.[DbSet].Find(Guid)` method. **Case 2: Default** The other `Types` (Billing, Schedule, Supervision, JobSetup, etc) would need the **PipelineID** parameter AND an `OrderByDescending(o=>o.AddDate)` statement where it would then retrieve the `FirstOrDefault()`. In both, I would need to check the `Property Value`